# Splitting up human body .obj into pieces

Tags: three.js, .obj

Currently I am loading a .obj file for the human body, and whenever I hover over the human body in the browser it changes color to red. I am trying to figure out how to split up the human body object into different pieces such as hands, arms, torso. Then once I have the human body object split into different pieces I can group them together, and hover over each body part and have the intersected body part change colors instead of the whole object. This is my first time splitting up an object, and I am looking for any tips or solutions on how to break up my human body .obj file so that I can change the color of the intersection on each individual body part.

This is currently what is happening, but I want to be able to split it up so I can have the the intersected body part light up.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You almost certainly want to do this in a modeling tool like Blender. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Another solution would be not split it up at all - the model looks like it's posed for rigging, so you could test to see which bone is closest to the mouse, and use a vertex shader to highlight the parts of the mesh close to the bone. It wouldn't be trivial though, and you'd still need Blender if it's not rigged yet.

Comment: Another option--though admittedly equally difficult--would be to determine vertex ranges (or index ranges) for each body part. The `Raycaster` could identify which vertex was hit, and that range could be converted to a draw group with a different material index.

Comment: Piggybacking off of TheJim01 above.. you could log the uv coordinate of the hit and do a rough rectangle area logging to get the regions. But honestly, splitting in blender is the way to go. Even if you just have an invisible split model for picking, and the complete solid model for display.

Comment: Raycasting manually against each face would also work... so would a million other things. But the answer here is - blender.

Answer (score 0):

Three.js is not supposed to be used for this kind of stuff. You can build a mesh manipulation tool using three.js but it would be very very involved, possibly larger than the three.js project itself.

Look into dedicated 3d modeling software like Maya, 3d Studio Max, Blender etc.

Modify your `body.obj` to either contain sub meshes or break it up into several `.obj` files.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I am going to go with the blender approach, and split the obj up into sub meshes, and use the ray caster implementation I have to figure out which mesh has been clicked. This will be my first time using blender so I will share my results when I am finished.